# imageButton in Android Programming

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a problem with a ImageButton in android programming, I put the logcat, if anyone can help me solve it:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: "android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myImageButton);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

From the log you're casting it to a `Button`, not an `ImageButton`. Two distinctly different objects.

Comment: oh mi god!!! is true, i,ve wrote Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myImageButton) but in the graphical layout i've use a ImagenButton. Thaks!!!

Answer (score 2):

This means that you cannot cast an ImageButton to a Button. Instead you need to approach your casting situation differently.

And the reason they canotn be casted is because:

### Following the flow of an ImageButton:

> java.lang.Object    ↳ android.view.View
>        ↳    android.widget.ImageView
>            ↳    android.widget.ImageButton

### Conclusion

Since it does not extend Button, you therefore cannot cast it to that type. Although the name is a misnomer because its called ImageButton..